# Vertically Center floating div elements using css only

Tags: css

So, I am trying to create a generic navbar which i can reuse.
The navbar has left and right sub-elements which are floating left and right respectively.

The problem is height of the left and right sub elements is variable depending upon the content inside(due to different font size,icon use and some other elements).

I have seen a lot of table and psuedo elements methods that work great for non floating divs.

Currently i am using jquery to calculate the height and use position absolute method to solve this issue.

Is there any way to achieve it using clean css?

```
<div class='navbar'> 
 <ul class='nav-left'></ul> //float: left
 <ul class='nav-right'></ul> //float: right
</div>
```

EDIT

I found a way to not apply float to both the elements,so it gets rid off position absolute method
Here is jsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/dyrotn71/

Comment: Can you demonstrate a simple version of the issue on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Hi..[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dyrotn71/)..  i have made  a small demo here.
This is a bit better than using absolute positioning method but do require the height of the two elements .. and also second one look proper.Applying float on both divs doesnt work.

Comment: You can add this to the question by editing it. Also what is the desired result? You want the left content to be vertically centered vs the right (in this particular case)? Like http://jsfiddle.net/dyrotn71/1/ ? remove the floats, why do you need them floating?

Comment: the desired result is that... no matter the height of left and right child... the elements should align themselves vertically center.How would you do it?Till now i have been adding padding and margins to each element everytime i have to create  a navbar.

Comment: I updated my previous comment to include a fiddle and asking why did you float the lists

Comment: its a nav bar ... so it will have some group of elements in the left-corner and some in the right corner.Check the bootstrap navbar http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar ... it also has navbar-left and navbar-right but doesnt support vertical alignment

Comment: You need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dyrotn71/2/ ? But it's without floats, it's inline-blocks.

Comment: @NikolayTalanov how would i keep the right element towards the right end?

Comment: What about 2 inline-blocks 50% width each and text-align: left for left block and text-align: right for right block?

Comment: @NikolayTalanov  50% width  wouldnt be great as the idea is to create  a rusable component

Comment: You want to place something between this blocks? Otherwise i have no idea why this is a bad solution.

Comment: @NikolayTalanov yes  exactly... it may be a searchbar along with some other button on the right .. and it can be some menu in the left

Comment: Than i guess pure css solution is only one - absolute position, top:50% and translateY(-50%). As in answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it need to be a float?

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar[class^=nav] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.nav-left {
  left: 0;  
}
.nav-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

That'll take care of it for you.

## [Another solution, no `position: absolute`](http://jsfiddle.net/dyrotn71/3/)

```
.navbar {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.navbar:after {
    content: '';
    clear:both;
    display: table;
}

.navbar .nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-right {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
}
```